# Working with matrix vs. character vector returns from vapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a vapply function which builds a matrix of returns with data from Google Maps. When the function is working with the geocode return of only one address, vapply coerces the matrix to a simple character vector of length 4. When more than one address is being processed a matrix is returned with nrows corresponding to the number of addresses coded. A simple example follows. I have a solution below but it strikes me as an inelegant path to achieve the desired output, namely a data frame with named columns. I also wonder if this opens me up to bugs by taking this approach. Is there a better way to flexibly create a data frame with these kind of changing character inputs?

```
# Save a dummy URL
geocode_url <- "https://www.google.com"

# Example: one row character return from vapply where matrix is coerced to character vector.
coord <- c(NA, NA, NA, "ZERO_RESULTS")

# Example: matrix return from vapply
coord <- matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, "ZERO_RESULTS",
                       NA, NA, NA, "ZERO_RESULTS", 
                       NA, NA, NA, "ZERO_RESULTS"),
                       ncol=4, nrow=3, byrow=T)

if(is.matrix(coord)){
    out <- data.frame(input_url=geocode_url,
                      lat=as.numeric(coord[ , 1]),
                      lng=as.numeric(coord[ , 2]),
                      location_type=coord[ , 3],
                      status=coord[ , 4])
} else if(length(coord)==4){
    out <- data.frame(input_url=geocode_url,
                      lat=as.numeric(coord[1]),
                      lng=as.numeric(coord[2]),
                      location_type=coord[3],
                      status=coord[4])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
if(is.matrix(coord)){
    out <- as.data.frame(coord)   
} else if(length(coord)==4) {
    out <- data.frame(t(unlist(coord)))
}

colnames(out) <- c("lat", "lang", "location_type", "status")
out$input_url <- geocode_url
out <- out[,c(5,1:4)]
out[,c(2,3)] <- lapply(out[,c(2,3)], as.numeric)
```